# Conversion locations between private geographical coordinate system and WGS84 in iOS

Tags: ios

I have a layer with a private geographical coordinate system in MapView in a iPhone or iPad. Now I need to show a gps location in this layer, if I use the seven parameters transformation algorithm to convert coordinate from WGS84 to my GCS, how should I do ?

Which method of the **CLLocationManagerDelegate** should I implement ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method isn't included in the frameworks. You'll have to code it yourself. There are examples around the web. If you search for something like `LLHToXYZ` or `LLA to ECEF` you can find implementations. This page has one in Javascript:

http://www.oc.nps.edu/oc2902w/coord/llhxyz.htm

Comment: Thanks so much! I implement it in Objective-C. I felt confused because I am new to iOS dev. Now I find it's easy to finish it with CLLocationManager and CLLocationManagerDelegate.